# SQLiteException no such table ITEMS (code1) : while compiling: SELECT * FROM ITEMS WHERE RECID =?

Tags: android, sqlite, foreign-keys, sqliteopenhelper

I'm trying to create a table `ITEMS` with a `FOREIGN KEY` that references the id of another table `UTILISATEURS`... While my table `UTILISATEURS` works just fine, the table `ITEMS` is not created for some reason. The error seems to be in the following query : `SELECT * FROM ITEMS WHERE RECID = ?`.

This is my class `ItemsDataBaseAdapter`

```
 public class ItemsDataBaseAdapter {

    static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Panier.db";
    static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
    public static final int NAME_COLUMN = 1;
    // TODO: Créer des attributs publics pour chaque colonne dans la BD
    // Requête SQL qui crée la DataBase

    static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "+"ITEMS"+
            "( " + "NAME text,PRICE integer,STORE text,IMAGEPATH text,RECID integer,ITEMID integer primary key autoincrement,"+ " FOREIGN KEY (RECID) REFERENCES UTILISATEURS (RECID));";

    public  SQLiteDatabase db;
    /*** Contexte de l'application qui utilise la DataBase***/

private final Context context;

    private ItemsDataBaseHelper dbHelper;
    public  ItemsDataBaseAdapter(Context _context) 
    {
        context = _context;
        dbHelper = new ItemsDataBaseHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }


    public  ItemsDataBaseAdapter open() throws SQLException 
    {
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }
    public void close() 
    {
        db.close();
    }

    public  SQLiteDatabase getDatabaseInstance()
    {
        return db;
    }

    public void insererEntree(String nomItem, Integer prix, String epicerie, String imagePath)
    {
       ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("NAME", nomItem);
        values.put("PRICE", prix);
        values.put("STORE", epicerie);
        values.put("IMAGEPATH", imagePath);


        db.insert("ITEMS", null, values);
    }
    public int supprimeEntree(String nom)
    {
        String where="NAME=?";
        int nbrEntreeSupp= db.delete("ITEMS", where, new String[]{nom});
        return nbrEntreeSupp;
    }   
    /*public ArrayList<Item> getEntreesUtilisateur(String id)
    {
        Cursor cursor=db.query("ITEMS", null, " RECID=?", new String[]{id}, null, null, null);
        if(cursor.getCount()<1) // Le RecID n<existe pas
        {
            cursor.close();
            return null;
        }
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        ArrayList<Item> listItems= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PASSWORD"));
        cursor.close();
        return mdp;             
    }*/

    /***Va chercher tous les items associés à l'utilisateur***/

    public ArrayList<Item> getEntreesUtilisateur(String id) 
    {
        ArrayList<Item> listeItem = new ArrayList<Item>();
        Item itemCourant;
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM ITEMS WHERE RECID = ?", new String [] {id}); 
        while (c.moveToNext())
        {
            String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("NAME"));
            int prix = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("PRICE"));
            String epicerie = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("STORE"));
            String imagePath = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("IMAGEPATH"));

            try
            {
                itemCourant = new Item();
                itemCourant.setNom(name);
                itemCourant.setPrix(prix);
                itemCourant.setEndroit(epicerie);
                itemCourant.setImagePath(imagePath);
                listeItem.add(itemCourant);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Ca a pas marché :(", "Error " + e.toString());
            }

        }

        c.close();

        db.close();
        return listeItem;
    }
    public void  updateEntree(String nom,int prix, String epicerie, String imagePath)
    {
        // Définition des colonnes modifiées
        ContentValues updatedValues = new ContentValues();
        // Allouer des valeurs pour chaque colonne
        updatedValues.put("NAME", nom);
        updatedValues.put("PRICE",prix);
        updatedValues.put("STORE",epicerie);
        updatedValues.put("IMAGEPATH",imagePath);

        String where="NAME = ?";
        db.update("ITEMS",updatedValues, where, new String[]{nom});            
    }

    }
```

This is my class `ItemsDataBaseHelper`

```
 public class ItemsDataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {

    public ItemsDataBaseHelper(Context context, String nom,CursorFactory factory, int version) 
    {
               super(context, nom, factory, version);
    }

    /*** Appelé s'il n'y a pas de BD pour en créer une***/

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db) 
    {
            _db.execSQL(ItemsDataBaseAdapter.DATABASE_CREATE);

    }
    /*** Appelé s'il y a déjà une BD et modifie les données dans celle-ci**/

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int _oldVersion, int _newVersion) 
    {

            // Upgrade the existing database to conform to the new version. Multiple
            // previous versions can be handled by comparing _oldVersion and _newVersion
            // values.
            // The simplest case is to drop the old table and create a new one.
            _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + "TEMPLATE");
            //Créer une nouvelle BD
            onCreate(_db);
    }


    }
```

This is my class `UtilisateursDataBaseAdapter`

```
public class UtilisateursDataBaseAdapter
 {
    static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Panier.db";
    static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
    public static final int NAME_COLUMN = 1;
    // TODO: Créer des attributs publics pour chaque colonne dans la BD
    /*** Requête SQL qui crée la DataBase***/

    static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "+"UTILISATEURS"+
            "( " + "USERNAME  text,PASSWORD text,RECID"+ " integer primary key autoincrement);";

    public  SQLiteDatabase db;
    /*** Contexte de l'application qui utilise la DataBase***/

    private final Context context;

    private UtilisateursDataBaseHelper dbHelper;
    public  UtilisateursDataBaseAdapter(Context _context) 
    {
        context = _context;
        dbHelper = new UtilisateursDataBaseHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    public  UtilisateursDataBaseAdapter open() throws SQLException 
    {
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }
    public void close() 
    {
        db.close();
    }

    public  SQLiteDatabase getDatabaseInstance()
    {
        return db;
    }

    public void insererEntree(String identifiant,String mdp)
    {
       ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("USERNAME", identifiant);
        values.put("PASSWORD",mdp);


        db.insert("UTILISATEURS", null, values);
    }
    public int supprimeEntree(String identifiant)
    {
        String where="USERNAME=?";
        int nbrEntreeSupp= db.delete("UTILISATEURS", where, new String[]{identifiant}) ;
        return nbrEntreeSupp;
    }   
    public String getEntreeMdp(String identifiant)
    {
        Cursor cursor=db.query("UTILISATEURS", null, " USERNAME=?", new String[]{identifiant}, null, null, null);
        if(cursor.getCount()<1) // l'identifiant n'exite pas
        {
            cursor.close();
            return "NOT EXIST";
        }
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String mdp= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PASSWORD"));
        cursor.close();
        return mdp;             
    }
    public void  updateEntree(String identifiant,String mdp)
    {
        // Définition des colonnes modifiées
        ContentValues updatedValues = new ContentValues();
        // Allouer des valeurs pour chaque colonne
        updatedValues.put("USERNAME", identifiant);
        updatedValues.put("PASSWORD",mdp);

        String where="USERNAME = ?";
        db.update("UTILISATEURS",updatedValues, where, new String[]{identifiant});             
    }

    public int getRecIdUtilisateur(String identifiant)
    {
        Cursor cursor=db.query("UTILISATEURS", null, " USERNAME=?", new String[]{identifiant}, null, null, null);
        if(cursor.getCount()<1) // l'identifiant n'exite pas
        {
            cursor.close();
            return -1;
        }
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int recId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("RECID"));
        cursor.close();
        return recId;
    }




}
```

Finally, this is my class `UtilisateursDataBaseHelper`

```
public class UtilisateursDataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
public UtilisateursDataBaseHelper(Context context, String nom,CursorFactory factory, int version) 
{
           super(context, nom, factory, version);
}
// Appelé s'il n'y a pas de BD pour en créer une
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db) 
{
        _db.execSQL(UtilisateursDataBaseAdapter.DATABASE_CREATE);

}
// Appelé s'il y a déjà une BD et modifie les données dans celle-ci
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int _oldVersion, int _newVersion) 
{

        // Upgrade the existing database to conform to the new version. Multiple
        // previous versions can be handled by comparing _oldVersion and _newVersion
        // values.
        // The simplest case is to drop the old table and create a new one.
        _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + "TEMPLATE");
        //Créer une nouvelle BD
        onCreate(_db);
}


}
```

Comment: Why do you set **2** database helpers? Also, Why do you create an Adapter and a Helper class? For me, all the **4** classes should be a single **1**.

Comment: At first I had only 1 helper, and i thought that the problem originated from that... So I tried to split it into two helpers, 1 for each table. But it didn't resolve the error.

Comment: The reason I need it is to associate every connected users with their own items, so when they are connected they only see what is theirs and not the entire table of items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved my problem. If you are creating more than one table in the same Database, it is better to wrap them in same DbHelper, therefore creating them in the same DbHelper instanciation.

Comment: `I finally resolved my problem.` ... With the help of **MY** comments. Because I really told you the same thing.